# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null :: My Javascript not working with HTML

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I am trying to reproduce this JSfiddle, https://jsfiddle.net/pvwtrbfd/

In chrome browser, on MacOS the same JS fiddle does not work.

I would really appreciate any help on this.

Thanks in advance.

## Below is the content of Filename.html file I am using:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>My First JavaScript</h1>
  <p>Here, a JavaScript </p>
  <script type="text/JavaScript">
    function getSel() // javascript
    {
      console.log("test");

      // obtain the object reference for the textarea>
      var txtarea = document.getElementById("mytextarea");
      // obtain the index of the first selected character
      var start = txtarea.selectionStart;
      // obtain the index of the last selected character
      var finish = txtarea.selectionEnd;
      //obtain all Text
      var allText = txtarea.value;

      // obtain the selected text
      var sel = allText.substring(start, finish);
      //append te text;
      var newText = allText.substring(0, start) + "<center>" + sel + "</center>" + allText.substring(finish, allText.length);

      txtarea.value = newText;
      console.log(newText);
      // do something with the selected content
    }
      document.getElementById("btnCenter").addEventListener("click", getSel);

  </script>

  <div>
    <button id="btnCenter">
      center
    </button>
    <br />
    <textArea id="mytextarea"></textArea>

  </div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You're attaching the event handler *before* the element exists. Put the `<script>` just before `</body>`, or use a document.load event handler.

Comment: This works! thanks a lot for suggesting this. I understand my mistake now. Thanks.